# in the new setting/surroundings

Tags: word-choice, word-request, idiomatic-language

James and the drunk enter the pizza place. Gordon's there.

Gordon: Who's that?

James: Oh, that's Shots.

Gordon: Shots?

James: Yeah. I don't know his real name. I'm not sure he does either. He's basically living in the pub across the street, so I thought I'd invite him over here and buy him a pizza.

Shots looks around the pizza place, seeming a bit uncomfortable in the new setting/surroundings.

My question is about the last part. Can I say "in the new setting" or "in the new surroundings" here?

Comment: My initial sense of it is that either could work. Both seem at a tad higher level of diction than the writing that comes before. I am failing to find a sample of what I'd offer as a better match in terms of diction.